# Use Principal Branch to Solve $\log\dfrac{i\pi}{3}=z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was working on a problem stating as

> Find all possible values $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that  $\log\dfrac{i\pi}{3}=z$.

I think I worked it out pretty quick but then I was a little bit confused about the principal branch.

**Here is my attempt:**

Firstly we have $$\log\dfrac{i\pi}{3}=\log i+\log\dfrac{\pi}{3}.$$

Then, the principal branch of $\log i$ is 
\begin{align*}
\text{Log}(i)&=\log|i|+i\arg(i)\\
&=0+i\dfrac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, we can conclude that $$z=\log\dfrac{\pi}{3}+i\dfrac{\pi}{2}.$$

However, the words "find all possible values" in the question alerts me to double check my answer, then I found a problem with the principal branch.

I used the principal branch to solve the problem, but should it be $$\log(i)=0+i(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi),$$ so that $$z=\log\dfrac{\pi}{3}+i(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)?$$

So the question here is that, when we deal with the logarithm of a complex number, we only use principal value or we use the infinitely many value?

Perhaps I totally misunderstood the principal branch.

Thank you for any corrections and inspirations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you cannot use $\log (ab)=\log\, a +\log\, b$ for complex numbers. There are infinitely many logarithms of $\frac {i \pi} 3$ and they are $\log (\frac {\pi} 3)+i(\frac {\pi} 2+2n\pi)$ where $n$ is an integer. The principal logarithm is $\log (\frac {\pi} 3)+i\frac {\pi} 2$. For the principal logarithm the imaginary part $\theta$ of the logarithm must satisfy $-\pi <\theta \leq \pi$.

You are right in saying that there is only one value for the principal branch of logarithm.

Comment: Got you! So there are infinitely many values of z in this question, right?

Comment: Right. There are infinitely many values of $z$ such that $e^{z}=\frac {i\pi} 3$ and they are all logarithms of  $\frac {i\pi} 3$.

Comment: Thank you so much!